# Volume of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 =a^2$ and over lemniscate $r^2=a^2\cos2\theta$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Volume of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 =a^2$ and over lemniscate $r^2=a^2\cos2\theta$

Now I am having trouble finding limits of integration.

I know limits for $z$ are $ \pm (a^2 - (x^2 + y^2))$ and limits for $r$ are $\pm (a \sqrt{\cos2\theta})$.

How do I find limits of $\theta$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Is lemniscate lies in 2D?

Comment: It becomes cylinder in 3-D

Comment: Limits for $z$ must be $\pm\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}$.

Comment: $\theta \in [0,2 \pi]$ Isn't that the case?

Comment: how to find value of theta was my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

In order to find the limits for $\theta$ notice that $\theta\in(-\pi/4,\pi/4)$ gives a curve in the right half plane. Also $\theta \in(\pi/4, 3\pi/4)$ gives a curve in the left half plane. Maybe drawing the graph can help you.

Comment: the lemnisate lies in 4=3rd , 4th quadrant also

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: You are  helping me answer my Question

Comment: Limits of theta ?????????

Comment: please elaborate how did you come with pi/4

Comment: At $\theta=\pm\pi/4$ the lemniscate meets itself in the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: I got $ \frac{8a^3}{3} (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4} )$  . .is this correct ?

Comment: I got $\frac{8a^3}3\left(\frac53-\frac{4\sqrt 2}3+\frac{\pi}4\right)$

Comment: what is the theta integral u got after solving

Comment: did you get integral of $sin^3\theta$